# Cannot Get DNS Requests via Java Code in Windows 10 and DLINK DIR-615 router

Tags: java, sockets, networking, dns

So I am working on a software that will monitor(and may alter by acting as a Forrowder) all the DNS requests made by my router.

**What I did?**

So for first I wrote a Java code that can listens to a specific port and prints all the requests to the console[For now I just want to test with the requests].

The code is:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class PortLogger{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LoggerServer loggerServer = new LoggerServer(53);
        loggerServer.start();
    }
}

class LoggerServer extends Thread{
    private int port;

    public LoggerServer(int port){
        this.port = port;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        try{
            int id = 1;
            ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port);
            System.out.println("Server Listening at port " + port);
            Socket client;
            while(true){
                client = server.accept();
                ClientHandler clientHandler = new ClientHandler(client, id++);
                clientHandler.start();
            }
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println("Exception at Server : 1 :: EX = " + ex);
        }
    }
}

class ClientHandler extends Thread{
    private Socket client;
    private int id;

    public ClientHandler(Socket client, int id){
        this.client = client;
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        try {
            String data = "";
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
            while(true){
                data = reader.readLine();
                if(data.length() > 0){
                    System.out.println("Client : " + id + " :: " + data);
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println("Exception at Client : " + id + " :: EX = " + ex);
        }
    }
}
```

The sole propose of this code for now is to Show me all the requests made to the server.

I know that I also have to change the DNS Server in my router for this.

So, for that I first tried by going to internet setup and put the local IP of my computer as DNS server.

But it was showing :

> DNS IP and LAN IP must be on different networks!

[image: IMAGE OF ROUTER NOT ALLOWING]

But I found another way to do it.

It is as follows:

I went to the setup wizard of the router and the set the DNS Server to the same IP.

Surprisingly this worked!

[I have no idea whether this is a bug in the D-Link Firmware or not.

[image: IP SUCESSFULLY ADDED]

I have also added an exception to allow all request both inbound and outbound to port 53.

**What is the problem?**

So now the problem is that even after successfully changing the DNS to my servers. There seemed to be no requests at all to the console. I tried a lot but nothing.

I checked that the program was working fine by voluntarily sending request to it using telnet?

Now am I doing anything wrong or there is some bug with the router(its is a old one).

NOTE: The black lines on the images are just to hide my public IP address nothing special.

EDIT: I tried a few more times then found that websites were not opening when I changed the DNS in my router but still nothing in the console!

Comment: Maybe DNS requests are resolved not by the router but by windows? Try changing windows DNS too: https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using#windows

Comment: @DelfikPro no i am sure that its resolved by the router as i gave the dns ips to the router  as well as i also tried previously to manually set the windos dns server ip to myself and s till there was no response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is difficult to give you a complete answer why your application doesn't work I can suggest some ways to investigate:

1. Port 53 is a privileged port. This means on Linux binding to that port requires root privileges and the application will throw an exception due to 'permission denied' if executed as a 'normal' user. As you are using Windows I don't know what it does if you try to bind as a 'normal' user, or you might be executing as an Admin user (or whatever the equivalent of 'root' is in Windows) and you don't know it. It might even just silently fail i.e. appear to bind when in fact it hasn't and no data is passed through you your application. As an aside, defaulting to 'root' as the default execution user in Linux is not the norm because it's insecure and most Linux distributions if not all do not allow this *by default* i.e. you can have this but you have to tell the distribution this is what you intend during installation. I'll let you come to your own conclusions what stance Windows takes for making users 'admin'...
2. In a scenario such as this if it were me I would immediately go to some networking tools to see what is happening. On Linux this is `tcpdump` or Wireshark. You can also get Wireshark for Windows as it's a GUI application. This will let you monitor and filter network traffic and so will be independent of your application. You can filter by source or destination address and/or port number.
3. I would leave the DNS setting alone in the router and change the DNS settings in one machine first, call it the *test client*, and set its DNS address to the machine where your application is running. Using `tcpdump` or Wireshark you can then make requests on your test_client e.g. browser requests and see the resulting network traffic.
4. You never mentioned if after changing your router's DNS settings all browser requests from clients fail. This is what I would expect to see if your router can no longer get a name resolution. However there maybe some DNS caching going on in your clients so you may appear to get successful DNS requests on your test_client. Again look at network traffic or use a Linux client which will provide you with much better networking tools.

Comment: Firstly incase of access denied i cannot find any errors both in normal user  mode as well as well as admin. Secondly i had already changed the settings for my computer but it had no difference. in wireshark i cannot find anything much related(maybe because i dont have much knowledge of Wireshark) and lastly you can assume for now i am not concerned about Linux as my primary target is wondows! and i would also like to mention that i am not sure whether the dns was  really changed in the router as i described in the question it could be a bug!

Comment: @JaysmitoMukherjee Not sure what you mean when you cannot find anything much related when using Wireshark. Does that mean you can't see any data going to port 53 on any machine? If it were me I would want independent confirmation that I see data going to port 53 in the first instance and then correct machine in the second. Linux may not be your primary target OS but nothing stopping you using it as a tool to investigate what is going on. Either way I think you need to read up on using Wireshark or some other means of sniffing network traffic.